# How to determine the simplified Unicode variant of a semantic variant of a traditional Chinese character?

Tags: unicode, cjk

As mentioned in an answer to [Simplified Chinese Unicode table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596576/simplified-chinese-unicode-table), the Unihan database specifies whether a traditional character has a simplified variant (kSimplifiedVariant). However, some characters have **semantic** variants (kSemanticVariant) which *themselves* have simplified variants. For example     U+8216 舖 has a semantic variant U+92EA 鋪 which in turn has a simplified variant     U+94FA 铺.

1. Should traditional to simplified mappings convert U+8216 to U+94FA?
2. If so, what's the easiest way of generating or downloading the full mapping, given that the Unihan database does not list U+94FA as a kSimplifiedVariant directly for U+8216, only for the intermediate form U+92EA?

Comment: First question sounds off-topic , it's linguistic related, actually depends on your apps logic, not programming related.